# How to add horizontal page break in interop excel worksheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel-interop

I am trying to add page break in interop excel file but not able to do it yet. Sometimes nothing happens and sometimes i gets exception "Unable to set the PageBreak property of the Range class".

Here is template file.

[Excel Template file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnOCP.png)

I am new to Interop Excel. I am using an excel file as template which is in PageBreakPreview. When i inserts data in new row then i want to shift page break after that row.
I have seen many suggested answers but could not get it done.

Here is some code (coomented) i have tried.

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
try
{
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath("~//Templates//ExcelTemplate.xlsx")
        , 0, true, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, misValue, misValue, true, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
    worksheet.Activate();
    worksheet.Cells[6, 1] = "Item1";
    worksheet.Cells[6, 1].Font.Bold = true;
    worksheet.Cells[7, 1] = "content";
    //worksheet.HPageBreaks.Add(sheet.Range["A7"]);
    //worksheet.HPageBreaks.Add(sheet.Range["A13"]);
    //xlWorkBook.Worksheets[0].ViewMode = ViewMode.Preview;
    //worksheet.Rows[5].PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual;
    //xlApp.ActiveWindow.View = Excel.XlWindowView.xlNormalView;
    //worksheet.Cells.PageBreak = (int)Excel.XlPageBreak.xlPageBreakNone;
    //worksheet.Rows[4].PageBreak = Excel.XlPageBreak.xlPageBreakNone;
    //worksheet.Rows[8].PageBreak = Excel.XlPageBreak.xlPageBreakManual;
    //worksheet.ResetAllPageBreaks();
    //worksheet.HPageBreaks[1].Location = worksheet.Range["A8"];
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~//TempFiles//ExcelFile_Copy.xlsx"));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //ex
}
finally
{
    xlWorkBook.Close(0);
    xlApp.Quit();

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
}
```

When data for new is added page break should get to the end of next row.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that whitish area on sheet is print area actually so i just updated the `xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1].PageSetup.PrintArea` and assigned new print area value to move PageBreak under 7th row which is automatic page break i think. Any one correct me if i am wrong.

It is what i did to solve my problem:

`xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1].PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$H$20";`

Answer (score 0):

Break the Excel worksheet to multiple pages and set view mode as page break preview.

```
workbook.Worksheets[0].HPageBreaks.Add(sheet.Range["A7"]);
workbook.Worksheets[0].HPageBreaks.Add(sheet.Range["A13"]);
workbook.Worksheets[0].ViewMode = ViewMode.Preview;
```

ps : A7 and A13 is the break

**EDITED**

Remove the specified horizontal Page Break by call the HPageBreaks.RemoveAt() method.

```
workbook.Worksheets.HPageBreaks.RemoveAt(7);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already tried this. First statement is indeed adding new page break in whitish area of excel sheet. But second line is not working. I am assuming at this point page break can only be added in whitish area may be? But i want to move existing page break (showing in blue line after 7th row in attached image) to next row. Just like when we drag page break with mouse to next row(s). Can it be done?

Comment: So you want the pagebreak to move after 7th row? How come its not working? Mine is working. Did you miss something?

Comment: I could not find **RemoveAt()** definition in **HPageBreaks**. I am using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**.
I found `worksheet.HPageBreaks[1].Delete();` to delete page break. I am having feeling that in file (as shown in image) below 7th row is automatic page break as i am getting HPageBreaks.Count as zero. I can add a pagebreaks but only that pagebreaks shows in file which is in whitish area of file. May be if we remove automatic page break (under 7th row in image) and add new one under next rows like A13.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. I have figured out solution through PrintArea property and it worked. :)